# Collision detection methods for 2D and 3D environments

Tags: algorithm

I found many sites, books and articles, all about especifics algorithms, I listed some of them (like *bounding boxes*, *bounding spheres*, *octrees* and *KD-tree*), but any of these founds lists every algorithm for collision detection, and thats what I need.

Someone knows the name of all algorithms (or at least some of them, any other algorithm would help) for collision detection, or knows where I can find it?

Comment: Also look into GJK and MPR (minkowski portal refinement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a book about real-time collision detection that contains a variety of algorithms for all sorts of intersection tests and lists a large number of collision detection algorithms. It's a decent overview if that's what you are looking for:

http://realtimecollisiondetection.net

https://books.google.com/books?isbn=0080474144